# While true difference between browser and a compiled program on the OS

Tags: javascript, while-loop, infinite-loop

Today I watched a colleague of my program a small game in Python on his Raspberry Pi. The game engine ran by using a `while(true)` or infinite loop. I myself use a websocket program in PHP that uses `while(true)`. In these examples a infinite while loop is used which doesn't cause the program to become unresponsive. Without it, it wouldn't work properly. However in JavaScript we need to avoid a infinite loop at all costs. When a loop becomes infinite the browser hangs and becomes unresponsive.

My question: What is the difference between a *infinite loop* running in a compiled *Python* program and a *infinite loop* written in *JavaScript* running in a browser?

Comment: no . both block the current thread.

Comment: @Hacketo then the python loop probably updates the UI, the JS-Code doesn't call the browsers render command.

Comment: @Sebb you mean do a repaint ?, because If in python you did not have control of the UI it should be the same result

Comment: @Hacketo In a way. When you make a game, you usually put it in a loop where the first call goes to the game logic to update positions, player health, cat count and something like this. After that, you call a render method so that your updated content is processed as a picture and send to the screen. Then you start again. In JavaScript, you omitt the call to the render function and therefore the browser's UI never updates.

Comment: Python lets you write multi-threaded code doesn't it? JavaScript doesn't (except via web workers).

Comment: On Java/Android you can easily block the UI thread, same as a "javascript" while loop. I don't understand the goal of the question.

Comment: To why this is blocking the UI. To stick with the game example. You can still click buttons and so forth. So why isn't this possible in a browser. Or on Android for that matter. I'm looking for insight. Reading the answers and comments are giving me more insight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main diffrence between the Python and the JavaScript code is that the Python code takes care of updating the UI, whereas the JS code just loops it's game logic and is therefore preventing the browser from updating it's view.

When you make a game, you usually put your in a loop where the first call goes to the game logic to update positions, player health, cat count and something like this. After that, you call a render method so that your updated content is processed as a picture and send to the screen. Then you start again. In JavaScript, you omitt the call to the render function and therefore the browser's UI never updates.

This has nothing to do with threading, but in a language like Pyhton (and many others) you can separate the game logic and the rendering so that when your logic is taking a while to do it's cat repositioning the programm is still able to update your screen (with the same, non-updated content over and over but that's another topic).

**TL;DR** The JavaScript blocks the rendering process of the Browser, whereas the Python loop explicitly calls the rendering function for it's UI.

For JS you should use `setInterval(function, time)`, as @RúnarBerg noted.

EDIT: @mouser noted that you can also use [web workers](http://www.w3schools.com/htmL/html5_webworkers.asp), which seem to be a html5 approach to multi-threading in JS. It may be worth a look if you are developing a game in JS, especially since it's supported in all major browser according to w3schools.

Comment: Very clear explanation. I saw the word webworker sail by. Could that be kind of a work around?

Comment: @Mouser This seems to be a good solutions with good browser support. I did never actually look into it, but I'll update the answer :)

Answer (score 6):

The difference is that the JavaScript runs on the browser's UI thread (preventing it from pumping normal OS messages like paint), whereas the Python program doesn't have a UI, and thus it doesn't matter if the main thread is hogged by your code.

You're still blocking the main thread either way, but in different contexts.

Answer (score 1):

In Python, your loop probably looks like this:

```
while true:
    TakeInput()
    DoStuff()
```

So each iteration of the loop does something, and it keeps doing that forever.

In JavaScript, the input usually comes from the browser. If your JavaScript code is looping forever, the browser never gets a chance to let your code know new input has arrived.

You could write JavaScript code like this:

```
while (true) {
    x = input('Give me input!');
    // Process x
    alert(result);
}
```

which would approximate the Python code, but that's not the way JavaScript usually works, and side-steps the browser all together.

Answer (score 1):

Javascript has asynchronous runtime, meaning that your code doesn't usually have to wait for other parts to continue. You can run an infinite non-blocking loop with `setInterval(fn, time)` which executes the function `fn` at an interval of `time` milliseconds.

Comment: That's a solution, but I think he's looking for an explaination.

Comment: @Sebb Indeed. I know how to mimic infinite looping in the browser by setting an interval with a very short timer. I wanted more insight in the difference between infinite looping within a browser and a non-browser program.